# Lambda for sending emails based on time

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, sam

I have a project that must have functionality to schedule email triggers. There are presentations, each presentation has a start date and time, I can set a trigger to send notification emails for users, and set hh:mm how long before the start of their presentation the letter should be sent.

**Example:**
if I set 00:01 users must receive an email before 1 minute of the presentation start

**My question:**
What is the best approach to implement this functionality?

My project is based on Serverless

My implementation:

- Save triggers in db
- Schedule lambda to invoke every 1 minute
- Lambda must scan triggers from DB and send emails to users according to time

But I have some concerns:

- Is this normal to invoke lambda every minute
- If I schedule trigger for 00:01 but in the moment after the scheduled lambda was invoked, do my users receive emails with a delay of 1 minute?

Comment: I'd really encourage you to take a look at EventBridge, specifically [Creating an Amazon EventBridge rule that runs on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html).  Create the event to trigger the Lambda at the time you need.  Have your DB contain an event identifier and the list of emails.  The Event will send the Lambda the event id and the Lambda will read the DB for the emails it needs to send.